# Using gtkmm with Eclipse CDT

Tags: linux, eclipse, gtkmm

I'm trying to compile the gtkmm [Simple Example](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtkmm-tutorial/2.21/sec-basics-simple-example.html.en) using Eclipse CDT, but it's not working for some reason

I'm compiling this on Mandriva Linux  and GCC 4.4.3

I get this error, which I think is a linking error :

```
Building target: Test
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -L/usr/include/gtkmm-2.4 -o"Test"  ./test.o   
./test.o: In function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0x39): undefined reference to `Gtk::Main::Main(int&, char**&, bool)'
test.cpp:(.text+0x43): undefined reference to `Gtk::Window::Window(Gtk::WindowType)'
test.cpp:(.text+0x4b): undefined reference to `Gtk::Main::run(Gtk::Window&)'
test.cpp:(.text+0x53): undefined reference to `Gtk::Window::~Window()'
test.cpp:(.text+0x5b): undefined reference to `Gtk::Main::~Main()'
test.cpp:(.text+0x82): undefined reference to `Gtk::Main::~Main()'
test.cpp:(.text+0x95): undefined reference to `Gtk::Window::~Window()'
./test.o: In function `global constructors keyed to main':
test.cpp:(.text+0xaf): undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::ustring(char const*)'
test.cpp:(.text+0xbe): undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
test.cpp:(.text+0xd2): undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::ustring(char const*)'
test.cpp:(.text+0xe1): undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
test.cpp:(.text+0xf5): undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::ustring(char const*)'
test.cpp:(.text+0x104): undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
test.cpp:(.text+0x118): undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::ustring(char const*)'
test.cpp:(.text+0x127): undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
test.cpp:(.text+0x13b): undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::ustring(char const*)'
test.cpp:(.text+0x14a): undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
test.cpp:(.text+0x15e): undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::ustring(char const*)'
test.cpp:(.text+0x16d): undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
test.cpp:(.text+0x181): undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::ustring(char const*)'
test.cpp:(.text+0x190): undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Test] Error 1
```

Sorry for the long error log, but I don't know how to make it shorter

Comment: Did you do whats said here: http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtkmm-tutorial/unstable/sec-install-unix-and-linux.html.en

Comment: I already have the devel package installed, or do you mean that I should compile it from source instead?

Answer (score 4):

Project Property->C/C++ Build->Settings
GCC C++ Compiler->Miscellaneous, add this string: `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs` into Other flags.
GCC C++ Linker->Miscellaneous, add this string: `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs` in Linker flags.
If you are using gtkmm 2.4, just replace "gtkmm-3.0" with "gtkmm-2.4"

Tick the GCC C++ COMPILER VERBOSE (_V) string.

Comment: Oh! This is better than mine! Much easier to add.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add all the library's listed when you run `pkg-config gtkmm-2.4 --cflags --libs` in a terminal to Eclipse. As far as I have found, Eclipse doesn't play nice with pkg-config, so you have to add them manually.

Right click your Project > Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings

Under GCC C++ Compiler, in directories, add each directory listed when you run
`pkg-config gtkmm-2.4 --cflags`
(just the directories, drop the -I and -pthread)

Under GCC C++ Linker, in Libraries, add everything from
`pkg-config --libs`
(again, just add the libraries,drop the -l and -pthread)

Comment: How do I found out which directories get listed using pkg-config?

Comment: output of `pkg-config --cflags` on my computer is:

Comment: output of `pkg-config --cflags` on my computer is:

`-pthread -I/usr/include/gtkmm-2.4 -I/usr/lib/gtkmm-2.4/include -I/usr/include/giomm-2.4 -I/usr/lib/giomm-2.4/include -I/usr/include/pangomm-1.4 -I/usr/lib/pangomm-1.4/include -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/include/gtk-unix-print-2.0 -I/usr/include/atkmm-1.6 -I/usr/include/gdkmm-2.4 -I/usr/lib/gdkmm-2.4/include -I/usr/include/glibmm-2.4 -I/usr/lib/glibmm-2.4/include -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include  ...`(there are more)

Take the -I(-'i' uppercase) off the front and add each individual directory with the add button.

Comment: (If you can't tell, I'm new here, still trying to figure this site out, bear with me)